# Telerik RadToolTipManager Tooltip position incorrect in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls, kendo-tooltip

I am using telerik `RadToolTipManager` control to show tooltip on html controls.(anchor tag, span label etc.) as below in my `.ascx` page in asp.net

```
<telerik:RadToolTipManager OnClientBeforeShow="BeforeShow_Tootip" ID="BVAutoRadToolTipManager" runat="server" ToolTipZoneID="tooltipZoneDiv" Position="TopRight" HideDelay="500" AutoCloseDelay="10000" Skin="Vista" AutoTooltipify="True">
        </telerik:RadToolTipManager>
```

above code is working fine in IE and FF and display tootip at TopRight as I set `Position="TopRight"` in markup.

**Issue:** Now, when I open my page in `Chrome` it show tooltip on correct position on page load first time. **but when I Scroll the page down** then the tool tip position is **far above the mouse pointer**.

Can you please give me a suggestions that Is there any way to set the position correct when user `hover` the element. How can we set position Using **`OnClientBeforeShow`** event of `RadToolTipManager`.

Thanks

Any help will be very much appreciated ..!!

Answer (score 2):

This was reported as a bug ([Wrong placement (position) of RadToolTip in Chrome 61](https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/230470-wrong-placement-position-of-radtooltip-in-chrome-61)). Workaround is to override the _getPosRelativeToMouse method.

This Js code should fix the issue.

```
Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.prototype._getPosRelativeToMouse = function (targetBounds) {
    var elemX = targetBounds.x;
    var elemY = targetBounds.y;

    //Get last recorded mouse position
    var pos = this._getMousePosition();
    var mouseX = pos.clientX;
    var mouseY = pos.clientY;

    //Take into consideration the offsetScroll!
    var standard = $telerik.standardsMode;
    //$telerik.standardsMode does not do a good job! Extra check is needed for FF!!
    //And yet another check needed for Safari! It should always be set to false in order to get the calculations right
    if (!$telerik.isIE && document.compatMode != "CSS1Compat") standard = false;
    else if ($telerik.isSafari && !(Telerik.Web.Browser.chrome && Telerik.Web.Browser.version >= 61)) standard = false;

    if (standard) {
        elemX -= $telerik.getCorrectScrollLeft(document.documentElement);
        elemY -= document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    else //NEW: Add support for quircksmode
    {
        elemX -= $telerik.getCorrectScrollLeft(document.body);
        elemY -= document.body.scrollTop;
    }

    //Calculate the position of the mouse, relative to the targetcontrol
    var deltaX = mouseX - elemX;
    var deltaY = mouseY - elemY;

    return { x: deltaX, y: deltaY };
}
```